# How to persist a guava hashcode with JPA?

Tags: jpa, hash, guava

I should want to save a [guava hashcode](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/HashCode.html) with JPA. How is it possible ? Is it in an int, long, String, or other thing ?

It's for hashcode of list of name/value pairs. (hashcode of list, not hashcode of name/value).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why that would be necessary to persist the hashcode? Normally the hashcode should compute very quickly.

Comment: It was for a fingerprint usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Guava HashCode is a wrapper around a byte array, which you can retrieve with HashCode.asBytes.